# what is CMPRS in top command in MAC OS X 10.10.2?

Tags: macos, shell

What is CMPRS in this top command output???

```
Processes: 264 total, 2 running, 9 stuck, 253 sleeping, 1229 threads
2015/04/13 17:17:48
Load Avg: 1.00, 1.22, 1.24 
CPU usage: 6.36% user, 21.81% sys, 71.81% idle 
SharedLibs: 14M resident, 16M data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 120250 total, 3283M resident, 82M private, 540M shared.
PhysMem: 7711M used (1109M wired), 478M unused.
VM: 693G vsize, 1068M framework vsize, 680833(0) swapins, 842308(0) swapouts.
Networks: packets: 3/224B in, 2/196B out.
Disks: 0/0B read, 0/0B written.

PID    COMMAND          %CPU TIME     #TH  #WQ #PORTS MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS     %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID FAULTS    COW    MSGSENT    MSGRECV    SYSBSD    SYSMACH   CSW        PAGEINS IDLEW POWER USER            #MREGS RPRVT  VPRVT  VSIZE  KPRVT  KSHRD 
98414  diskmanagementd  0.0  00:00.50 0    0   0      0B     0B     0B     98414 1     sleeping *0[0]      0.00000 0.00000    0   0         0      0          0          0         0         0          0       0     0.0   root            0      -96K   -32M   0B     0B     0B    
96595  periodic-wrapper 0.0  00:00.03 0    0   0      0B     0B     0B     96595 1     sleeping *0[0]      0.00000 0.00000    0   0         0      0          0          0         0         0          0       0     0.0   root            0      -16K   -16M   0B     0B     0B
```

Command I am using is top -d -r -l 0 -s  0.

Answer (score 3):

CMPRS indicates the # of bytes (not bits) of compressed data belonging to your process.

**EDIT :** Check this [article](http://macs.about.com/od/macoperatingsystems/fl/Understanding-Compressed-Memory-in-OS-X.htm) for more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, interesting; It's compressed memory and [this article](http://www.quora.com/How-does-Mac-OS-X-10-9-Mavericks-compressed-memory-work) describes it nicely:

> ... However, in the event that this purge still isn't enough, OS X will
>   begin using the WKdm algorithm (as Massimiliano Raber states in
>   another answer) to begin compressing memory that is marked as
>   inactive.

I looked at the [Apple *fork* of `top`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-100.1.2/), but didn't find anything describing it.